# Jenkins Java_Home path doesnt look like a JDK directory

Tags: java, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I have configured Jenkins on AWS RHEL-8.6 EC2 instance. Also setup the java path variable in
bash profile. I am getting below error while configuring JDK path in Jenkins.

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.342.b07-2.el8_6.x86_64 doesn’t look like a JDK directory
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.342.b07-2.el8_6.x86_64
PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME:$HOME/bin
[root@ip-172-31-0-152 ~]# find /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8* |head -n 20
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.342.b07-2.el8_6.x86_64
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is maybe a mistake in your initial PATH.
Login to your account and open `.bash_profile` file in your `/home`. You can use vi or nano to edit it from your terminal...

```
 nano ~/.bash_profile

export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.342.b07-2.el8_6.x86_64

export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Don't forget to update your current user sesssion from a terminal to activate the new path settings : `source ~/.bash_profile`

Comment: Is your file `java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.342.b07-2.el8_6.x86_64` a `.rpm` file ? If it is, did you install it before ? Because when i m searching this file name on google, i can see rpm file...